# i don't know what is wrong with my coding it keeps skip to else statement even i type in integers not float

Tags: python

```
def factorial(n):
    if isinstance(n,int):
        if n == 1:
            return 1;
        elif n <= 0:
            print("Factorial is for positive integer.")
        else:
            return n*factorial(n-1)
    else:
        print("It's only for integers")

factorial_number = input("give an integer that you want to factor: ")
print(factorial(factorial_number))
```

Comment: `input` returns a string regardless of what you type.

Comment: Maybe read the python docs about ``input``?

Comment: input is returning a string, you need to typecast it as needed, (to int, im guessing here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle is as soon as you get the input, see below example:

```
if factorial_number.isdigit():
    factorial_number = int(factorial_number)
else:
    print("It's only for integers")
```

Comment: Won't work with negative numbers which are valid integers. Wrap in a try/except instead; "easier to ask for forgiveness than permission"

Comment: @roganjosh although true in general, it would be fine in this case because factorials are only defined for non-negative integers

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `input()` always return a `str` object. You need to cast it to `int`.

```
factorial_number = int(input("give an integer that you want to factor: "))
print(factorial(factorial_number))
```

Comment: thx for helping